# Why hashchange event doesn't fire on www.google.com?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to execute my JavaScript code on every search via www.google.com. When I search e.g. the word "stackoverflow" `location.href` looks like:

> https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow

So `location.search === ""` and `location.hash === "#q=stackoverflow"`.

Then I write in Web Console:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    console.log("hash changed");
}, false);
```

Then if I type e.g. "banana" in the search field and hit "Enter" the `location.href` will be:

> https://www.google.com/#q=banana

But the "hashchange" event **won't fire** in the latest Chrome and Firefox. I'll see nothing in Web Console. But it will fire if I change the URL in the location bar to https://www.google.com/#q=orange manually or if I change the URL via `location.href = "https://www.google.com/#q=milk"`. Why?

p.s. The www.google.com doesn't reload when you hit "Enter" in the search field. Actually I do it for a browser add-on and mentioned Web Console only for simplicity.

Comment: Have you tried this with a test page that is not Google?

Comment: @AtesGoral Yes. The hashchange event fires if I click `<a href="#sometnig">something</a>` on my test web-page.

Comment: But... it's google.  You're hitting enter in a form field which should create a new request.  At that point the page reloads.  Unless you're intercepting the form submit event it'll go though, change the page, and not fire any hash change event.

Comment: @JosephMarikle The page doesn't reload. The form doesn't fire "submit" event.

Comment: @traxium You found any answer.?

Comment: @SurajJain yep, the accepted answer is right. I used Proxy/Reflection API to "intercept" `history.pushState` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google changed to using history.pushState, which doesn't trigger the onhashchange event to fire.